# How can I use the Android Studio profiler to profile the shutdown of an app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, profiler, shutdown, onpause

I am trying to find the root cause of an 'Activity pause timeout' in an Android app built through Unity. When calling `Application.Quit()` in C#, the app shuts down accordingly but I get the following line in the console log;

```
W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{64fc124 u0 com.my.app/com.my.app.MyPlayerActivity t229}
```

followed by;

```
I/ActivityManager: Process com.my.app/ (pid 31633) has died: cch  CRE (321,519)
```

This implies that the app isn't shutting down correctly, and is being killed before it can process the pause logic.

I have a debug version of the project (built with Unity 2018.4.16f1 and IL2CPP backend) and I am trying to use the Android Studio profiler to understand what threads are running at this point in the app. However, each time I tried to profile, the trace results fail to stop or parse due to the app shutting down.

I have tried stopping the trace early but this appears to miss any 'pause' calls in the app, or will still overthrow the end of the app and not parse properly.

How can I profile this area of the code using Android Studio's profiler? What are the alternatives to try to inspect and debug this behavior?

Comment: have you tried with ADB, running app on your device while plugged on your PC?

Comment: I haven't tried script debugging the app no. However, last time I checked I couldn't step into native Java code.